# Renaming multiple filenames in PowerShell sometimes doesn't work

Tags: powershell, rename

I asked a question where I was trying use PowerShell to remove parts from the names of numerous files in numerous folders. The possible parts that needed to removed were " - xx_xx" " - yy_yy" " - zz_zz" etc.

To do that, I'm using this:

```
Get-Childitem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace " - xx_xx","" -replace " - yy_yy","" -replace " - zz_zz",""}
```

It works great.

However, I received a note that for a specific project the naming conventions are going to change. To something like "-xx_xx-yy_yy-A-B" or "-xx_xx_zz_zz-A-B" or "-xx_xx_yz_yz-A-B" etc... Notice that there are no spaces. I thought I could just simply sub this in and it would work, something like:

```
Get-Childitem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $.Name -replace "-xx_xx-yy_yy-A-B","" -replace "-xx_xx_zz_zz-A-B","" -replace "-xx_xx_yz_yz-A-B","" }
```

but ... it doesn't work. I thought it might have something to do with the hyphens, but escaping them out doesn't work either unless I somehow did that incorrectly, which is very possible.

This is the error message I get:

```
Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed. The term '$.Name' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:47
+ ... em -NewName { $.Name -replace "-xx_xx-yy_yy-A-B","" -replace "-xx_xx- ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (True Dialog Requests-xx_xx-yy_yy-A-B.htm:PSObject) [Rename-Item], Para
   meterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentInvocationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

1. How do I get this to work
2. Why is it working with " - xx_xx" etc. and not now?
3. Is there just a better way to do both?

Comment: It's probably better to complete the get-childitem first.  `(Get-Childitem -Recurse) | rename-item `

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$_.Name`

```
Get-Childitem -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "-xx_xx-yy_yy-A-B","" -replace "-xx_xx_zz_zz-A-B","" -replace "-xx_xx_yz_yz-A-B","" }
```

Comment: That's it.Thanks so much. Can't believe I just left out a _

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using VBA for this task.
Before you use it, you must install from References:

 **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**

In the column A is the existing names inside of the folder.
In the column D is what names should they have.

```
Sub RenameMultipleFiles()
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = -1 Then
        selectDirectory = .SelectedItems(1)
        dFileList = Dir(selectDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & "*")
    
        Do Until dFileList = ""
            curRow = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            curRow = Application.Match(dFileList, Range("A:A"), 0)
            If curRow > 0 Then
                Name selectDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & dFileList As _
                selectDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & Cells(curRow, "D").Value
            End If
    
            dFileList = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

If you don't have the list of existing file names in the Column A here is example how you can collect them:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ListAllFiles()
Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("Your Path")
Call getFilesDetails(objFolder)

End Sub

Function getFilesDetails(objFolder As Scripting.Folder)
Dim objFile As Scripting.File
Dim nextRow As Long
nextRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
   Cells(nextRow, 1) = objFile.Name
   nextRow = nextRow + 1
Next
End Function
```